# Can I display a windows.forms message box over a browser window?

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a login validator that was written for a windows app ans uses Messagebox to display error messages, but the project I'm working on is an asp.net webapp. They work when called by my aspx.cs page but they always appear behind the browser. Is there a way I can make them appear as top most? I tried this trick but it just stopped the call from working:

```
   Form f = new Form();
   f.TopMost = true;
   MessageBox.Show(f, resultMessage, "MEDS Configuration Manager", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

Comment: Using `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` is not likely going to work on other operating systems and should be avoided.

Comment: Can you show us how do you call this login validator?